# Raspberry pi remote storage over mobile internet

Tags: nas, raspberry-pi, hybrid-storage, online-storage

Cannot find right tools to achieve fallowing:

`IP camera (hikvision) -> Raspberry pi as NFS/SMB server for camera -> 4G internet -> NAS (storage) backend`

Camera and raspberry pi is located at remote location. What I want is to mount storage from my home where I have NAS (QNAP). (In case if someone stoles my camera and raspberry, I have data at my home)

Raspberry pi will provide NFS/SMB share to IP camera. Requirement is some kind of caching in raspberry pi in case if internet connection is lost. When connection with NAS is restored, then it syncs changes with NAS.

What options I have?

- Mobotix camera is not an option because they are expensive.
- 64GB flash drive and rsync is last option
- carefully, in hard to find place, hide raspberry?
- use google cloud storage?

Answer (score 0):

Use Dropbox: save video on dropbox on the raspberry, then dropbox wil move it on the nas and on the nas you should put a procedure thet once the file is downloaded (or once dropbox space is running out) removes files from dropbox storing them only on the NAS.

Another option is to bring up a VPN between nas an raspberry, then mount NFS storage from the nas onto the raspberry over the VPN and program a cronjob that periodically (once every 1/4 hour) tries to move from NFS storage between raspberry and camera to the NFS between raspberry and NAS. NOTE: if mobile connection is slow, I suggest to split videos in short files, so NFS could resume more easly.

Comment: Rsync then is much easier to implement.

Comment: But it sends data in plaintext VPN are chiphered and dropbox uses TLS

Comment: Rsync can send files via ssh. It's secure enough